# Problem applying conditional CSS class using Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a span showing an account balance.  You can click on it to edit that balance.  You can see below I'm applying the class `hidden` to the elements when the editing variable is changed.

```
<span @click="updateEditAccount(true, false)" v-bind:class="{ hidden: account.editing == true }">Balance ${{ account.balance }}</span>
<input v-bind:class="{ hidden: account.editing == false }" type="number" step="0.01" v-model="account.balance" >
```

This is the method that changes that value

```
updateEditAccount(editValue, updateLedger) {
    this.account.editing = editValue
    alert(this.account.editing)
    if(updateLedger) {

    }
},
```

When I set the initial value to true or false it displays the correct one.  When the method is called I can see that the value is changed correctly.

The hidden class is simplye a `display:none;`

So the value does change, but the visible element doesn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is common [reactive problem](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html). You can use `Vue.set`

```
updateEditAccount(editValue, updateLedger) {
    this.$set(this.account, 'editing', editValue)
    if(updateLedger) {

    }
}
```

**Updated:**

Or you can use deep copy:

```
updateEditAccount(editValue, updateLedger) {
    this.account.editing = editValue
    this.account = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.account))
    if(updateLedger) {

    }
}
```

**ES6**

```
updateEditAccount(editValue, updateLedger) {
    this.account = {...this.account, editing: editValue}
    if(updateLedger) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I made this changed, but have the same issue.  Both ways change the value.  If I check the value after it's updating, the model has the correct value, but the displayed element doesn't change.

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you try deep copy solution?

Comment: There is a case `this.account.editing` is updated but Vue component is not rendered again.

Comment: Ok, so the deep copy worked, but would you be able to tell me why it was an issue?  I looked at your link, but didn't understand the correlation.

Comment: As my understanding, when you update `this.account.editing`, `this.account` is still point to old object and Vue doesn't recognize data change. It doesn't re-render HTML element. It only re-render if `this.account` object change.

Comment: That answer does make sense, though it seems like a problem they should fix.

Comment: Aside from the deep copy, is there a way to force the refresh?

Comment: You might want to try `this.$forceUpdate()`, but I'm not sure this work. I usually use deep copy with ES6 syntax.